# round округляет float до нуля

Tags: php

Почему выражение `round(4.993, -1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);` возвращает 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что [параметр](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php), до какой цифры округлять, стоит -1, так что округленное значение будет ближайшим кратным 10,  из ряда ...-10, 0, 10, 20...

> Если precision отрицателен, округление будет производиться слева от
> запятой. Если абсолютное значение precision больше или равно
> количеству цифр, результат округления будет равен 0